# Separable spaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a closed separable subspace $A$ of a non separable Hilbert space $H$, then is $A^\perp$ separable. If so what would be a way to prove it, if not why.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is a countable dense subset of $A$ and $T$ were a countable dense subset of $A^{\perp},$ then $S + T = \{s +t : s \in S, t \in T \}$ would certainly be a countable dense subset of $H,$ contrary to hypothesis.

Further edit: Since this seems to have got a downvote, let me fill in details. We have $H = A \oplus A^{\perp},$ since $A$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $H$. Suppose that $S$ is countable and dense in $A$ while $T$ is countable and dense in $A^{\perp}.$ Choose $h \in H$
and write (uniquely) $h = c + d$ with $c \in A, d \in A^{\perp}.$ Choose any $\varepsilon > 0.$ Then there is $s \in S$ with $\| c - s \| <\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and there is $t \in T$ with $\| d - t \| <\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$ Then $\|h - (s+t) \| < \varepsilon$. Now $S + T$ is certainly countable, and we have proved that it is dense in $H,$ contrary to the fact that $H$ is separable. Hence $A^{\perp}$ can't be separable if $A$ is separable.